# Find the equation of a parabola which passes through the points $(5,10),(−5,0),(9,−6)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the equation of a parabola which passes through these points $(5,10),(−5,0),(9,−6)$ using the formula $y = ax^2 +bx + c$.

Would there be a vertical axis that is symmetric with the points?

Comment: Substitute the points into the parabola and solve for $\;a,b,c\;$ ...

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding an equation of circle which passes through three points](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827072/finding-an-equation-of-circle-which-passes-through-three-points), same question, same OP.

Comment: @amWhy I don't think so, since that question is about a circle, whereas this one is about a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Since the parabola passes through the points $(5,10),(−5,0),(9,−6),$ we can solve for $a$, $b$ and $c\,$ in: $$\left\{\eqalign{&10=5^2a +5b+c \\ & 0=(-5)^2a+(-5)b+c \\ & -6=9^2a+9b+c}\right.\ ,$$
to find your equation describing the parabola.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if a point $P=(\alpha,\beta$) is on the parabola, then $\beta = a\alpha ^2 + b\alpha +c$

You gotta find three coefficients so you need three conditions...

Answer (score 0):

y = a(x+p)^2 + q

If one of those points are the turning points then you will have your -p and q value. Then substitute any other point to get your a value.