# Best fit circular arc to an elliptical arc?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

Is there a standard procedure or algorithm for finding the best fit circular arc to an elliptical arc ?

Where the ellipse arc is:

1. symmetrical about the minor axis, subtending $[+\theta, -\theta]$ from the centre.
2. $\theta$ is between $0$ and $90$ degrees

It seems obvious that the centre of such a circular arc is on the minor axis and I can get good results graphically, but cannot find any analysis of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will be the *best* fit but it would certainly be a *good* fit:

Pick the three points on the ellipse at $-\theta$, $0$, and $+\theta$ and then fit a circle to them as detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827072/finding-an-equation-of-circle-which-passes-through-three-points).

If no one is able to provide an analytical solution for the *best* fit then I can provide a numerical solution.